# The legacy expo-cli does not support Node +17

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm, npm-package

I have installed expo-cli and set the env variable. It gives this error:

The legacy expo-cli does not support Node +17. Migrate to the versioned Expo CLI (npx expo).
Uncaught Error Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\a.expo'

Node Version: v18.12.1
npm version: 9.1.3

Answer (score 12):

I got the same error after installing a package. After some digging I noticed that the version system has expo dependencies "^1.0.0".
As a result, I updated it as " npx expo upgrade " and my application worked.
[before npx expo upgrade](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9CFx.png)

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and I used `npx expo-cli upgrade` command inside of the project directory and my problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should start with `npx expo start`.

Comment: This does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is having a similar problem, noticed that using an outdated CLI (the legacy cli) was causing issues when some of the commands in the expo documentation were not working for me. For instance, I tried to run `npx expo customize metro.config.js` and the command was not recognized.

I attempted to fix it using the first answer in this post, and when running `npx expo upgrade` I got the following error:

```
Error: yarnpkg exited with non-zero code: 1
    at ChildProcess.completionListener (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/spawn-async/src/spawnAsync.ts:65:13)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1091:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
    ...
    at spawnAsync (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/spawn-async/src/spawnAsync.ts:26:19)
    at YarnPackageManager._runAsync (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/package-manager/src/NodePackageManagers.ts:314:31)
    at YarnPackageManager.addWithParametersAsync (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/package-manager/src/NodePackageManagers.ts:259:16)
    at YarnPackageManager.addAsync (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/package-manager/src/NodePackageManagers.ts:263:5)
    at upgradeAsync (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/src/commands/info/upgradeAsync.ts:496:7)
    at actionAsync (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/src/commands/info/upgradeAsync.ts:42:3)
```

I had to first run `yarn upgrade expo`, and then `npx expo upgrade` and it seems to have fixed the expo CLI error. I am able to run the initial `npx expo customize metro.config.js` command successfully as well.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem -

```
$ npm install --global expo-cli // 1st command

$ expo init demo_app // 2nd command
WARNING: The legacy expo-cli does not support Node +17. Migrate to the new local Expo CLI: https://blog.expo.dev/the-new-expo-cli-f4250d8e3421.

[14:38:50]

Migrate to using:

› npx create-expo-app --template

[14:38:51] Input is required, but Expo CLI is in non-interactive mode.

--template: argument is required in non-interactive mode. Valid choices are: "blank", "tabs", "bare-minimum" or any custom template (name of npm package).
```

- Node version - v18.17.1
- NPM version - 9.8.1

---

**Steps to fix this issue -**

1 - uninstall expo-cli:

```
npm uninstall --global expo-cli
```

2 - Install Expo CLI (version 4 or higher):

```
npm install --global @expo-cli
```

3 - Create a New Expo TypeScript Project:

```
npx create-expo-app demo_app --template expo-template-blank-typescript
```

4 - Navigate to Your Project:

```
cd demo_app
```

5 - Install react-native-web@~0.19.6:

```
npm install react-native-web@~0.19.6
```

6 - Install react-dom@18.2.0:

```
npm install react-dom@18.2.0
```

7 - Install @expo/webpack-config@^19.0.0:

```
npm install @expo/webpack-config@^19.0.0
```

8 - Run project:

```
npm run web
```

[image]

Comment: there is no @expo-cli  instead  use npm i @expo/cli

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade expo with compatibility :

```
expo upgrade
```

**The please allow after step:**

```
Would you like to proceed? ... yes

√ You are already using the latest SDK version. Do you want to run the update anyways? This may be useful to ensure that all of your packages are set to the correct version. ... yes
```

Answer (score 0):

For my part, it's simple. I simply cloned my project and launched: "`npm install`" then: "`npx expo start`"